# How to Automatically Select a ListBox Item Based on the Current Month (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datetime, ms-access, listbox

I have a Visual Studio program that imports selected checkboxes into an Access Database as a new record. One of the items that also gets imported is a ListBox value. All the items, including the ListBox's selected item, are inputted into the database fine.

At the current moment, the user has to manually select the ListBox item. I would like the ListBox item to be chosen automatically.

The ListBox's contents are a range of Month/Year combinations ranging from "January 2021" to "December 2021", I would like the Month/Year combination to be chosen in accordance with which month and year it is whenever handling mybase.load occurs. For example: a current date/time of "5/11/2021 12:11:21" would automatically choose "May 2021" The day and specific time don't matter.

Below is my attempt at the automatic selection. I have added December so that I can test the program now. If there are other components that would better serve me, please feel free to voice your opinion!

Here's my code for that sub:

Private Sub MonthSelectionLogic() Handles MyBase.Load

```
    If DateTime.Now.ToString = ("12/dd/2020 HH:mm:ss") Then
        MonthList2021.SelectedItem = "January 2021"
    End If

    If DateTime.Now.ToString = ("1/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") Then
        MonthList2021.SelectedItem = "January 2021"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It may not be appropriate but you might also use a `DateTimePicker`. You can simply assign the current date or date/time to the `Value` property with the `Format` set to `Custom` and the `CustomFormat` set to "MMMM yyyy". That will then display the current month name and year. The rest of the date and time will still be stored in the control but not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
MonthList2021.SelectedItem = Date.Now.ToString("MMMM yyyy")
```

No need for an `If` statement. The "MMMM" format specifier is for the full month name, e.g. "January", "MMM" is for the abbreviation, e.g. "Jan", "MM" is for the padded number, e.g. "01", and "M" is for the unpadded number, e.g. "1".